# How can I identify an Azure SQL Database as DEV only so that I do not get charged?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I have created a new Azure Database and I want to start developing against it. Is there a way to indicate that this database is a DEV only database? I do not want to get charged for it until I am ready to go to production. Is there such an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally, a singelton Basic database starts at $5/month [[link]](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/sql-database/). Combined with an Azure Free Trial [[link]](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/), one can make this offer stretch quite a bit for a dev environment.

Answer (score 1):

When you create new website you can also choose to create new free database for this website